# How to close a site for django?

Tags: python, django

I want to restrict access to a django site, how to restrict it to an IP adress or make it to open by login and password

should I use htaccess or code it inside django itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block it with username and password use your htaccess.

If you want to restrict it for certain IPs, create a file on your server, name it however you want.

Add this line to your nginx project conf:

`include blockips.conf;`

Your `blockips.conf;` should look like this:

```
deny all;
allow your_ip_address_here;
```